# Opening multiple window with same ViewModel using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

This question is in reference to this link [Opening new window in MVVM WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845689/opening-new-window-in-mvvm-wpf).
I want to open new window in some service.
Following is my code

This is a window service which I am calling from ViewModel

```
public class WindowService : IWindowService
{
    public void ShowWindow(object viewModel)
    {

        var win = new Window {Content = viewModel};
        win.Show();
    }
}
```

Following is my App.xaml code

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:MainViewModel}" >
        <viewModel:ChildWindow />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now this works fine for all windows which have different ViewModel.
But when I want to open another window which is using same view model but their view is not same,I can not define data template of same type in App.xaml.

How do I open multiple new window which have same ViewModel?
Should I create different ViewModel for each window?

Answer (score 1):

I have shown an alternative way of opening and closing windows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512972/385995).

You could add a `DependencyProperty` e.g. `DataContext` to the `OpenCloseWindowBehavior`, use it to pass the ViewModel, and hook up the window's `DataContext` to this ViewModel in the code of the behavior. Tell me if you need more help.

```
<local:OpenCloseWindowBehavior WindowType="local:YellowWindow" Open="{Binding YellowOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding SomeViewModel}" />
```