# WPF - Window doesn't close

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I used the following answer to get a new window and be able to use the values in another ViewModel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512972/3793542

I implemented this to my application, where a user can add a new Customer. To do this, he/she clicks the button in the CustomerDetailsView, and a new window opens (CustomerAddView). Then he/she fill out the details and clicks the button in the window.
Now, **the Customer is added, my ListBox updates just fine. But the window doesn't close.**
I was hoping that any of you can spot what's wrong, as I can't seem to be able to figure it out and it's been driving me crazy.

**The code**
The OpenCloseWindowBehavior as mentioned in the linked answer is the same, only renamed to WindowBehavior.

Here's the view where the button is, CustomerDetailsView (shortened a bit):

```
<UserControl x:Class="QRM.View.CustomerDetailsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:src="clr-namespace:QRM"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:QRM.View"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:QRM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:QRM.Helpers">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:CustomerDetailsViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../StylesRD.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <!-- TwoWay binding is necessary, otherwise after user closed a window directly, it cannot be opened again -->
        <helpers:WindowBehavior WindowType="view:CustomerAddView" Open="{Binding AddCustomerOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <!-- Grid with all the details-->
        </Grid>

        <Line Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource horizontalLineStyle}" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="True"> Add a new customer</Button>
            <!-- More buttons-->
        </StackPanel>

        <Line Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource horizontalLineStyle}" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Vertical">
            <!-- More buttons-->
        </StackPanel>    
    </Grid>        
</UserControl>
```

The new window CustomerAddView:

```
<Window x:Class="QRM.View.CustomerAddView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:QRM.ViewModel"
        Title="Add Customer" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:CustomerAddViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../StylesRD.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Form to put in new Customer's details-->

        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,50,0,0"
                Command="{Binding AddConfirmCommand}">Add this customer</Button>
    </Grid>            
</Window>
```

CustomerDetailsViewModel:

```
public class CustomerDetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bool isSelected = false;
        private Nullable<bool> isVisible = new Nullable<bool>();
        DBCustomer dbCustomer = new DBCustomer();

        #region Constructor
        public CustomerDetailsViewModel()
        {
            Messenger messenger = App.Messenger;
            messenger.Register("CustomerSelectionChanged", (Action<Customer>)(param => ProcessCustomer(param)));
        }
        #endregion

        #region Add a Customer
        private bool _addCustomerOpen;
        public bool AddCustomerOpen { get { return _addCustomerOpen; } set { _addCustomerOpen = value; OnPropertyChanged("AddCustomerOpen"); } }

        private RelayCommand addCommand;
        public ICommand AddCommand
        {
            get { return addCommand ?? (addCommand = new RelayCommand(() => AddCustomer())); }
        }

        private void AddCustomer()
        {
            this.AddCustomerOpen = true;
        }

        //After pressing the button in AddView
        private RelayCommand addDoneCommand;
        public ICommand AddDoneCommand
        {
            get { return addDoneCommand ?? (addDoneCommand = new RelayCommand(() => AddCustomerDone(), () => !isSelected)); }
        }

        public void AddCustomerDone()
        {
            App.Messenger.NotifyColleagues("NewCustomer");
            this.AddCustomerOpen = false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region PropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

CustomerAddViewModel:

```
class CustomerAddViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private RelayCommand addConfirmCommand;
        DBCustomer dbCustomer = new DBCustomer();

        public ICommand AddConfirmCommand
        {
            get { return addConfirmCommand ?? (addConfirmCommand = new RelayCommand(() => AddConfirmCustomer())); }
        }

        private void AddConfirmCustomer()
        {
            if (!dbCustomer.Create(newCustomer))
            {
                return;
            }
            CustomerDetailsViewModel _closeTheWindow = new CustomerDetailsViewModel();
            _closeTheWindow.AddDoneCommand.Execute(false);
        }

        private Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
        public Customer NewCustomer
        {
            get { return newCustomer; }
            set { newCustomer = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NewCustomer")); }
        }

        #region PropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you create *new* instance of CustomerDetailsViewModel here:

```
CustomerDetailsViewModel _closeTheWindow = new CustomerDetailsViewModel();
_closeTheWindow.AddDoneCommand.Execute(false);
```

This instance is not related to anything and it's AddCustomerOpen property is not bound to anything either, so setting it has no effect.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I now use my Messenger to call the method