# WPF Open/Close Window Behavior not working for ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, behavior, showdialog

I've found [this behavior here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512972/8433039%22this%20behavior%20here%22) whilst searching for a way to open/close windows in viewmodels. I implemented the behavior more or less exactly as stated in that answer, except that I changed the inherited `Behavior<UserControl>`to `Behavior<Window>`, as I used the behavior in a `Window` and not a `UserControl`.

Everything worked well until I tried to change the `window.Show()` to a dialog `window.ShowDialog()`. After closing the newly opened window, it would not reopen again.

I figure that has something to do with the way dialogs work?

Is there a way I can change that behavior so it would work with dialogs as well?

(Or did I actually make a mistake implementing it, causing it not to fully function? (In case it works for other people))

Comment: I much prefer a `WindowManager` type of service of some sort for handling this.  `WindowManager` understands the mapping between views and view-models, and can open and close windows as needed.  It is usually exposed through messaging, or as a property on a base view-model class.  It makes interacting with the UI much more pleasant.  With a proper `interface` it is easy to unit-test as well.

Comment: If you are interested in seeing my own implementation, you can see the source code [here](https://bitbucket.org/BradleyUffner/wpflib/src/c285d0e6e45ef9efe25458c7dbe076f35d8927bd/WpfLib/Services/WindowManager/WindowManagerService.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-defaultc).  All other MVVM libraries that I've looked at have some sort of mechanism for handling this.